# Python multiprocessing - Modify JSON via multiple processes

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to modify a JSON file with `multiprocessing`. I would be able to split the JSON into chunks, so that each process has only access to and modify a certain part of the JSON (so it's guaranteed that no two processes want to modify the same attribute). My question is, how can I share the JSON object between processes so that the changes are reflected on the original object? I know, that `multiprocessing` passes the object as a copy, so I'd need to use a `Manager()`, but how exactly can I do that? Currently I have

```
def parallelUpdateJSON(datachunk):
    for feature in datachunk: 
        #modify chunk

def writeGeoJSON():
    with open('geo.geojson') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(0, mp.cpu_count())):
        #chunk data into a list, so I get listofchunks = [chunk1, chunk2, etc.,]
        #where chunk1 = data[0:chunksize], chunk2 = data[chunksize:2*chunksize] etc.
    pool.map(parallelUpdateJSON, listofchunks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    with open('test_parallel.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

But of course this passes the chunks as copies, so the original `data` object doesn't get modified. How can I make it so that `data` actually gets modified by the processes? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a queue in which you put the json objects to modify, and another queue in which the processes will put the result

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a better idea to avoid synchronous access to your output file.  It will be a lot easier to just produce N partial outputs and join them together into a property of your json object.  Then you can dump that object to a file.

```
def process(work):
    return str(work[::-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool()
    structure = json.loads("""
    { "list":
        [
            "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
            "the quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox"
        ]
    }
    """)
    structure["results"] = p.map(process, structure["list"])
    #print(json.dumps(structure))
    with open("result.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(structure, f)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd also have to `return datachunk` in `parallelUpdateJSON` right?

Comment: Also, I get `TypeError: 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable` for this.

Comment: Probably because as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply) states "func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool", so it doesn't map the function to all the chunks, it just launches a single process.

Comment: Sorry.  The apply_async was wrong, should symply have been map.  The essence however was to not share the result between workers.

Comment: @ite__: yes, you'ld have to treat your `parallelUpdate` as a (sequential!) function returning a result.

Comment: Still, there's a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`, you can't concat strings with a JSON object, that is represented as a `list`.

Comment: Ok.  I was too optimistic about that.  Obviously you should just add the results into the 'parent' json structure instead of string concatenating.  I'll see if I can adapt my answer.